# How to redirect a www url to non-www url using 301 permanent redirection?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My website is running on `virtualmin` control panel's virtual server currently it is redirecting 302 temporary URL while I have added redirection rule in `.htaccess` file.

Here is my `.htaccess` file configuration:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^(([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)?)\.html$ page.php?pagId=$1
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^example.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]
```

Kindly let me know what changes I need to make in my web server so it redirects correctly 301 permanent redirection?

I want to redirect all requests for my domain in this URL format "https://example.com/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by writing two rewrite rules. One in each vhost

i keep the same in .htaccess file
>

```
         Options -Indexes
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteBase /
         RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
         RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
         RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L,NC]
         RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.html$ page.php?pagId=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

And in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file
>

```
        <VirtualHost*:80>
        .
        .
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
        </VirtualHost>


         <VirtualHost*:443>
        .
        .
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
        </VirtualHost>
```

Now it's working fine.

Hope this may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.html$ page.php?pagId=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava for your help but still not working still 302 redirection.

Comment: Which URL did you enter in browser and what didn't work? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.